# Sublime text 3 font options directwrite

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime text 3 and change my font face to `Inconsolata`.

However, after changing this, I cannot show Chinese on my editor. I only can set `directwrite`  to font options to modify this problem but my `Inconsolata` will be set as `no round`.

Does someone know how I can modify the problem that my sublime cannot show Chinese without font options ?